# how to define matrix in mainwindow.cpp c++

Tags: c++, qt, matrix

```
 spectre=spectrum->dft(uhd_samples,Ndft,noise_power);
    bool conclusion=stat->test(noise_power,&spectre,Ndft,lambda,Nsamples);
```

I had 2 errors in  qt creator:

```
/home/hoss/cdf/mainwindow.cpp:45: error: cannot convert 'Matrix {aka std::vector<std::vector<float> >}' to 'MainWindow::Matrix*' in assignment
         spectre=spectrum->dft(uhd_samples,Ndft,noise_power);

/home/hoss/cdf/mainwindow.cpp:46: error: no matching function for call to 'AD_test::test(float&, MainWindow::Matrix**, int&, float&, int&)'
         bool conclusion=stat->test(noise_power,&spectre,Ndft,lambda,Nsamples);
                                                                             ^
```

`dft` returns a matrix so I have to define spectre as matrix. I tried to create `struct matrix`... but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because you are trying to assign a value to a pointer.  As `dft(..)` returns a value, you should change your `spectre` variable to store a copy of it.  Also it is not entirely clear if `Matrix` and `MainWindow::Matrix` are the same type - they need to be for assignment to be successful (or at least be implicitly convertible).

The second error is *probably* (you haven't provided the real signature of `AD_test::test(..)`) because `spectre` is a `MainWindow::Matrix*` and you are taking the address of it again resulting in a `MainWindow::Matrix**`, when more than likely it requires a `MainWindow::Matrix*` so fixing the first issue should solve this one too.